# ASP.NET Random string showing up in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, localhost

I am developing website using Asp.Net 4.5 (VS2012) and using Telerik Ajax controls.  I am using Telerik Schedular, Grid, AjaxPanel etc.

Project compiles fine. When I run it from VS.. It is showing me URL like this

> `http://localhost:23482/default.aspx`

and then suddenly some random string inserted between URL. and it looks little wired like below

```
"http://localhost:23482/(S(hchi1ir5xii2dy1cjgpghqx3))/default.aspx"

"http://localhost:23482/(S(mgxsfl3rnxnbx2y24i12nowe))/default.aspx"

"http://localhost:23482/(S(sc2hyowh0f2xidnx1zptgaqd))/default.aspx"
```

I've also tried to run it from IIS as website. no luck.. same problem.

NOTE: The website still works fine even with random strings in URL nothing is broken at all.

Can anyone please suggest me something ?|

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you are using cookieless session

[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Comment: Yes, You're right! Thank you. +1 This is fastest answer I've ever got on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @HiteshRiziya you keep count of time for answers and give them awards??  :)

Comment: btw, do you know, Does that make any difference if we use cookieLess session with Telerik ?

Comment: @HiteshRiziya, I don't think so, it shouldn't make any difference to use CookieLess session with Telerik, However I haven't done that.

Comment: <sessionState cookieless="true" />

Answer (score 3):

SessionId by default is store in cookies but you can use cookieless  session by writting this lines to web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
         />
     </system.web>
```

you can remove that lines from webconfig to remove **(S(hchi1ir5xii2dy1cjgpghqx3))**

from

```
"http://localhost:23482/(S(hchi1ir5xii2dy1cjgpghqx3))/default.aspx"
```

or write to web.config

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="false"
          />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: This is still showing me sessionid in URL.

EDIT: oh ok. I just set cookieless="False" and it worked!

Comment: write <sessionState cookieless="false"
         regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" /> in web.config

Comment: Yeah. After making cookieless="false". problem gone. Is there any need to write regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" ?